# my kali linux won't recognize my external wifi adapter

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, usb

this question is asked everywhere and not a single clear answer is giving , like where is all **neo's**?
alot of us are running kali linux for the purpose of learning pen testing or networking ,and almost all of us are having the problem where the kali doesn't recognize the external wifi adapter, in iwconfig it shows         no wireless extensions.
at the bottom of the VM there is a usb icon and it says my adapters name.

Comment: Run _sudo rfkill list ; sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 ; sudo lsusb -v_ then highlight the text which appears. Copy it with Ctrl-Shift-C then return here, click [edit], and paste the results into your question. You may also wish to pose your question in the Kali=specific websites http://kali.org/blog & http://forums.kali.org If neither answer your questions, the Kali IRC channel is #kali-linux & can be found on irc.freenode.net.

Answer (score 1):

> this question is asked everywhere and not a single clear answer is giving

That's because it's well known that Kali has trouble with Wifi drivers. So if you want to do Wifi hacking on your own machine or in a VM, **don't use Kali.**

Use some distro that's meant for Linux beginners, or meant to be installed to a VM. You'll have all the hacking tools Kali has (though you need to install them).

> alot of us are running kali linux for the purpose of learning pen testing

And pen testing means "put Kali on a USB stick, walk into a company, hack their computers". That's not what you are doing. You are installing Kali on a VM on your own computer.

> [for the purpose of learning...] networking

Again, Kali is not suitable for learning. You can learn networking a lot better on a distro where you don't have headaches installing drivers, or where the package management does work out of the box with no headaches.

Kali is not "what all the hackers use". Nobody uses Kali on his own machine. No matter what you read on some forums. Because if you try to use Kali on your own machine, this only leads to "questions asked everywhere".

With always the same answer: **Don't use Kali for that.**

Comment: "And pen testing means "put Kali on a USB stick, walk into a company, hack their computers". That's not what you are doing. You are installing Kali on a VM on your own computer."
idk where you live but u can go to jail for doing that without lawyers,i can set up other pc's on VM and pen test them,so don't act like you helped making mr robot,if u can help then help if u can't then dont comment.